# Ajax login using jquery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need some help with the login system.

Im following this tutorial:
http://tutsforweb.blogspot.pt/2012/05/ajax-login-form-with-jquery-and-php.html

Everything works fine and its exactly what I want for my login system, but instead of only make login if the username and password are correct and displaying the message "Wrong username or password" if:

- the fields are empty
- username doesnt exist
- password is wrong

I wold like to make it to display a diferent message for each one of cases

Can someone tell me how to do that? Pls, I understand 0 of ajax and jquery.

This is the code of index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login_a").click(function(){
        $("#shadow").fadeIn("normal");
         $("#login_form").fadeIn("normal");
         $("#user_name").focus();
    });
    $("#cancel_hide").click(function(){
        $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#shadow").fadeOut();
   });
   $("#login").click(function(){

        username=$("#user_name").val();
        password=$("#password").val();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
            success: function(html){
              if(html=='true')
              {
                $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
                        $("#shadow").fadeOut();
                        $("#profile").html("<a href='logout.php' id='logout'>Logout</a>");

              }
              else
              {
                    $("#add_err").html("Wrong username or password");
              }
            },
            beforeSend:function()
            {
                 $("#add_err").html("Loading...")
            }
        });
         return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="profile">
    <a id="login_a" href="#">login</a>
    </div>
    <div id="login_form">
        <div class="err" id="add_err"></div>
        <form action="login.php">
            <label>User Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" />
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
            <label></label><br/>
            <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login" />
            <input type="button" id="cancel_hide" value="Cancel" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="shadow" class="popup"></div>
</body>
```

And this is the code of login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['pwd'];
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','logintest');

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if( $num_row >=1 ) {
            echo 'true';
            $_SESSION['user_name']=$row['username'];
        }
        else{
            echo 'false';
        }
?>
```

PS: I had other topic with some wierd code edited by me, but I think this is more expecific of what Is my problem and what I want.

If someone could help me I appreciate that.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you should ***never*** store passwords in plain text like this.  If anybody besides you uses this system, it's grossly irresponsible to mishandle other people's passwords.

Comment: Also, there should be *no* difference in the message between "username doesn't exist" and "password is wrong".  If the login fails, tell the user that it failed.  But don't tell them *which* of the two elements was wrong.  That gives them an opportunity to harvest usernames, which is half of what they need to break in.

Comment: @David, I'm not seeing where your second comment applies.

Comment: @dcclassics: Where the OP states: `"I wold like to make it to display a diferent message for each one of cases"`.  What's the OP is suggesting is very bad practice and should not be implemented.

Comment: Ahh!  Gotcha.  I was just looking through the code. Sorry.

Comment: I want to make this login system like the mediafire gots, when you try to login in mediafire, they are telling you if your password is wrong. I think that if a user try to login and its displays the error, he wont know if his login fails because of password, or the nickname or both, I think its useful to display the exact error.

Comment: @user3692074: Yes, it would be useful to the user.  It would also be useful to the user if you just let them in without needing a password at all, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea.  Giving away information about usernames and passwords to unauthenticated users is in every way a bad idea.  Whatever site you're getting that from shouldn't be doing it, and neither should you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Within the scope of functionality you are trying to achieve, I think you would want to handle all the 3 additional conditions from PHP only (though first condition of fields being empty can be checked using jQuery) but to keep it clean, you can test all the conditions using PHP and return different cases from php that will be accordingly handled by jQuery.

To give you understanding of how ajax and jquery are working here, looking at these lines of code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
        success: function(html){
```

The ajax methods call the login.php file by POSTing data on it. Whatever is returned or echoed by PHP will be fetched in the success function through the parameter 'html'. Note that 'html' is just a variable name being used here though actually just a string will be fetched here.

E.g. In the php, if login is successful 'true' is echoed and the same text is fetched in html variable in the success function. The condition if(html=='true') just checks that and hides the form.

One way to achieve your objective is you define different return values for each case from PHP which can be:
1: Login successful
2: One of the fields (username or password) are empty
3: Username doesn't exist
4: Password is wrong

For which the PHP code will be like this:

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        $username = $_POST['name'];
        $password = $_POST['pwd'];
        // Check if any of the fields is empty
        if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
            echo '2';
        } else {
            $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','logintest');

            // Check if username exists
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
            $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($num_row == 0){
                echo '3';
            } else {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
                $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
                $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                if( $num_row >=1 ) {
                    echo '1';
                    $_SESSION['user_name']=$row['username'];
                }
                else{
                    echo '4';
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

Now, these returns values can be handled in jQuery with switch statement

```
success: function(html){
              switch(html)
              {

                case '1': // Login successful 
                        $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
                        $("#shadow").fadeOut();
                        $("#profile").html("<a href='logout.php' id='logout'>Logout</a>");
                        break;

                case '2': // Empty Field
                    $("#add_err").html("Please fill both username and password");
                        break;
                case '3': // username doesn't exist
                        $("#add_err").html("Username doesn't exist");
                        break;
                case '4': //Password is wrong
                        $("#add_err").html("Password is wrong");
                        break;
            }
        }
```

I hope this will help you getting what you want

Comment: OMG, its exacty what I want, its perfect, thank you very much.

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing? In my database I have a field what is "activated" (yes or no), if the field is yes, the user should be able to make login, if its no, he wouldnt be. Can you please edit the cod and add this 5th case? PLS?

Comment: I dont need it anymore I figured out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

It is better to not change the error message.
For security reasons almost all login script will give as little information as possible.
The reason is that hackers will get the information as well and for example, they know that the username that was filled out is correct and can try to brute force the password.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of plugins and tools you can use to validate that the form elements (username and password) have values before making the AJAX request.  But at its simplest you can just check the input values yourself.  Notice where you get those values:

```
username=$("#user_name").val();
password=$("#password").val();
```

Those two variables are now string variables.  You can examine their contents and respond accordingly.  So perhaps before making the AJAX request you do something as simple as:

```
if (username === '' || password === '') {
  $("#add_err").html("Please enter both a username and a password");
  return false;
}
```

That way if either of those values is an empty string it will display an error and exit the function.  If both of them are not empty strings, it continues with your current code.

A couple of other important notes (which I made in comments above, but are important enough to include in an answer)...

1) ***Never store passwords in plain text.***  Seriously, never.  There's no reason to ever do this.  Passwords should be obscured by a 1-way irreversible hash.  Store that hash.  When a user enters their password, hash what they enter and compare the hashes.  You should ***never*** be able to read somebody's password.

2) Don't create different error messages depending on *how* the login fails.  Just say that the login failed and that's all.  Telling them which piece was wrong (the username or the password) provides an opportunity for an attacker to gather information about users.  Even a small opportunity, but it makes the attacker's job easier.  Don't give out such information.

Comment: Thx for your asnwer, yes, I know about the passwords, I didnt used any encryprion for now to have the code more clean and simple as possible. Later I will do it.  About the error, yes you are right, but also if a user try to login and its displays the error, he wont know if his login fails because of password, or the nickname or both, I think its useful to display the exact error.